# How to sum equal key values when inserting them into a new dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary, key

I have the dictionary that I got from a .txt file.

```
dictOne = {
             "AAA": 0,
             "BBB": 1,
             "AAA": 3,
             "BBB": 1,
           }
```

I would like to generate a new dictionary called dictTwo with the sum of values of equal keys. Result:

```
dictTwo = {
             "AAA": 3,
             "BBB": 2,
           }
```

I prepared the following code, but it points to error syntax (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`):

```
import json

dictOne = json.loads(text)
dictTwo = {}

for k, v in dictOne.items():                  
    dictTwo [k] = v += v
```

Can anyone help me what error?

Comment: You cannot have a dictionary such as dictOne due to duplicate keys. Maybe show what your input text file really looks like

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.  If a key occurs more than once in a dict (or in a json file), it replaces any previous value.  The original value(s) cannot be recovered.

Comment: Are you sure the original data is a dictionary, not a list?

Comment: Also, it looks like the syntax error might be coming from an extra `= v`. And as anyone else has mentioned, you cannot have duplicate values on a dictionary

Comment: as well as what previous comments said, the syntax error is this part: `= v += v` ... you should use either `= something` or `+= something` but not both

Comment: @EnriqueBet The extra space is unusual but not in itself a syntax error. The syntax error comes from what follows on that line

Comment: @Vlad thanks for pointing it out, edited my comment'

Comment: @Vlad Thanks for the replies. Really, dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys (although they are in the file, since they are str). Then I will put the repeated values in a list and sum them. It was the only way I found. =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you resolve the duplicate key issue in dict

```
dictOne = {
         "AAA": 0,
         "BBB": 1,
         "AAA": 3,
         "BBB": 1
       }

dictTwo = {
         "AAA": 3,
         "BBB": 2,
       }

for k, v in dictOne.items(): 
    if k in dictTwo:
        dictTwo [k] += v
    else:
        dictTwo[k] = v

print(dictTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you do it while reading the JSON input.

JSON permits duplicate keys in objects, although it discourages the practice, noting that different JSON processors produce different results for duplicate keys.

Python does not allow duplicate keys in dictionaries, and Python's `json` module handles duplicate keys in one of the ways noted by the JSON standard: it ignores all but the last value for any such key. However, it gives you a mechanism to do your own processing of objects, in case you want to do something else with duplicate keys (or produce something other than a dictionary).

You do this by providing the `object_pairs_hook` parameter to `json.load` or `json.loads`. That parameter should be a function whose argument is an iterable of (key, value) pairs, where the key is a string and the value is an already processed JSON object. Whatever the function returns will be the value used by `json.load` for an object literal; it does not need to return a `dict`.

That implies that the handling of duplicate keys will be the same for every object literal in the JSON input, which is a bit of a limitation, but it may be acceptable in your case.

Here's a simple example:

```py
import json

def key_combiner(pairs):
    rv = {}
    for k, v in pairs:
        if k in rv: rv[k] += v
        else: rv[k] = v
    return rv

# Sample usage:
# (Note: JSON doesn't allow trailing commas in objects or lists.)
json_data = '''{
             "AAA": 0,
             "BBB": 1,
             "AAA": 3,
             "BBB": 1
           }'''

consolidated = json.loads(json_data, object_pairs_hook=key_combiner)
print(consolidated)
```

This prints `{'AAA': 3, 'BBB': 2}`.

If I'd known that the values were numbers, I could have used a slightly simpler definition using `defaultdict`. Writing it the way I did permits combining certain other value types, such as strings or arrays, provided that all the values for the same key in an object are the same type. (Unfortunately, it doesn't allow combining objects, because Python uses `|` to combine two dicts, instead of `+`.)

This feature was mostly intended to be used for creating class instances from json objects, but it has many other possible uses.